# What is the meaning of "just as well" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The family cemetery sat at the bottom of the hill from the mansion.
>   Dan thought it was kind of stupid they'd hired a hearse to carry Grace
>   a hundred yards down the driveway. They could've put wheels on the
>   coffin like they have on suitcases and that would've worked **just as
>   well**.

Does this "just as well" have the same meaning of "just as well" in "It's just as well we'd prepared everything beforehand."

Comment: That's two questions.

Comment: I've just added the 2nd question, because I only know the meaning of "just as well" in that example and equivalents. And I don't think so they are the same.I'm only worried about my 1st question.

Answer (score 4):

The phrase in the first sentence equates to "equally well".

The phrase in the second sentence equates to "it's a good thing."

So, no, they do not have the same meaning.

Comment: In this sentence: "It would be just as well to ask his permission". Does this have the meaning of "equally well" too?

Comment: If you're saying "It's in my father's study and it would be just as well to ask his permission to get it" - then it would be equivalent to "It's a good thing."  If you're saying "It's in my parents study but my mother is busy so it's just as well to ask my father's permission" then it's in the "equally well" category.

Comment: (Excuse the bad punctuation. Cell phone keyboards are not great for this. )

In the second case, it could be argued that it could be both meanings but I was presenting it as I could ask my father or mother, mother is busy so it's equally good to ask father.